# PHP Session issue on browser close

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

Here running into problem where I have requirement to clear user session when closing the browser. I have tried all the various option like setting session.cookie_lifetime=0 or session_destroy on browser close using onunload function. But nothing seems to destroy session when I open the browser next time.

I just googled a bit and I saw that in Chrome browser there is setting called ''Allow local data to be set' that has to be changed to 'Keep local data only until I quit my browser', when I do this it does not retain my session.

The real problem is I cannot ask each user to change the settings of the browser and then it would work accordingly, is there a way I can handle it in code using php or javascript. Any option is fine.

Comment: you may have to live with that till google fixes it.

Comment: So there is no solution which we can inject as of now?

Comment: I think session will automatically destroyed when browser is closed...Anyway can you share your code what you have done..

Comment: Alok in normal scenario it does destroy sessions, you can try setting that option in google chrome browser where it says "allow local data to be set", set it and then try to close browser and open it again your session wont be destroyed. You can try that with any of you project if you have it locally it will behave same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking for both cookie and session when your page loads?  Something like this:

1) destroy cookie on unload
2) on page load check for both

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'] && $isset($_SESSION['user'] {
    //user is logged in
} else {
    //your code should fall here after user closes browser
    //because the cookie doesn't exist anymore.  Maybe you can even destroy the session too
    [session_destroy();]
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes that logic is already in place. But still it is a browser specific problem where it does not work.

Comment: Check this out, maybe it'll be helpful: http://erlycoder.com/111/google-chrome-session-cookie-expiration-issue-feature-your-personal-data-is-insecure-now-